# Why I am getting error from pipe and map from the following code?

Tags: angular

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http;
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { IBasket } from '../shared/models/basket';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BasketService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  private basketSource = new BehaviorSubject<IBasket>( null );
  basket$ = this.basketSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getBasket(id: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'basket?id=' + id)
      .pipe(
        map((basket: IBasket) => {
          this.basketSource.next(basket);
        })
      );
  }

}
```

and this is my basket.ts model

```
import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid';

export interface IBasket {
    id: string;
    items: IBasketItem[];
}

export interface IBasketItem {
    id: number;
    productName: string;
    price: number;
    quantity: number;
    pictureUrl: string;
    brand: string;
    type: string;
}

export class Basket implements IBasket {
    id = uuidv4();
    items: IBasketItem[] = [];
}
```

above this code I am getting error pipe and map from basket-service.ts. What is perfect format for this code? Also basket.ts model showing error into import. I am new in angular. please help me.
I am getting this error message -

> Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<IBasket, void>' is not assignable
> to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Object, void>'.   The 'Object'
> type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the
> 'any' type instead?
> Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'IBasket': id, itemsts(2345)

Comment: What is the error? Include this in your post

Comment: I have updated my post with error message. Please help me

Comment: you need to define the generic type for the get method: `this.http.get<IBasket>`

Comment: Wow. Thanks. The error has gone. when I define the generic type <IBasket>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replace the code from

```
return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'basket?id=' + id)
```

To

```
return this.http.get<IBasket>(this.baseUrl + 'basket?id=' + id)
```

then my problem has been solved and error has gone.